# Pagination with KNP Paginator is not working at all

Tags: symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I tried very hard to get the KNP Paginator to work.

I only want to oder an Entity to the id, but the pagination accept all the params but does noting with it!

Here´s my code:

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

**The Controller class:**

```
class StartController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $dql   = "SELECT a FROM MainArtBundle:Art a";
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);


        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $request->query->get('page', 1)          /*page number*/,
            8                                        /*limit per page*/
        );
        $pagination->setUsedRoute('homepage');

        if (!$pagination) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Art entities.');
        }
        return $this->render('MainShowBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
                             'pagination' => $pagination,
        ));
    }
```

**The Twig Template:**

```
<li>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Oldest', 'a.id', {'direction': 'desc'}) }}</li>
<li>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Newest', 'a.id', {'direction': 'asc'}) }}</li>
```

**The ArtEntity** (the entire Entity because perhaps the mistake is caused by the entity, can it be)

```
<?php

namespace Main\ArtBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Main\LikeBundle\Entity\Thumb;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Art
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="art")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Main\ArtBundle\Entity\ArtRepository")
 */
class Art
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $locale
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="locale", type="string", length=5, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $locale;

    /**
     * @var arrayCollection $user
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="arts")
     *
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $visits
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Main\ArtBundle\Entity\ArtVisit", mappedBy="art", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     *
     */
    protected $visits;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $tags
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tags", inversedBy="arts", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $tags;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $feature_partner
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Main\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="feature_partner")
     *
     */
    protected $feature_partner;

    /**
     * @var string $headline
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=false, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $headline;

    /**
     * @var \Main\StorageBundle\Entity\Image
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Main\StorageBundle\Entity\Image")
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @var string $content
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", unique=false, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $content;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text",  unique=false, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var datetime $contentChanged
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content_changed", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field={"headline", "content"})
     */
    private $contentChanged;

    /**
     * @var  integer $viewed
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="viewed", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $viewed;


    /**
     * @var object $CommentThread
     *
     */
    private $thread_id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $thumbs
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Main\LikeBundle\Entity\Thumb", mappedBy="entity", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $thumbs;




    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->feature_partner = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->thumbs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->commentThread = new \Main\ArtBundle\Entity\CommentThread($this->getId());

        /*$request = new Request();
        $this->locale = $request->getLocale()*/;

    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getHeadline();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $this->user = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set tags
     *
     * @param integer $tags
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tags
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    /**
     * Set headline
     *
     * @param string $headline
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setHeadline($headline)
    {
        $this->headline = $headline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get headline
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getHeadline()
    {
        return $this->headline;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Set contentChanged
     *
     * @param \DateTime $contentChanged
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setContentChanged($contentChanged)
    {
        $this->contentChanged = $contentChanged;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contentChanged
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getContentChanged()
    {
        return $this->contentChanged;
    }

    /**
     * Set feature_partner
     *
     * @param integer $featurePartner
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setFeaturePartner($featurePartner)
    {
        $this->feature_partner = $featurePartner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get feature_partner
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getFeaturePartner()
    {
        return $this->feature_partner;
    }

    /**
     * Add feature_partner
     *
     * @param \Main\UserBundle\Entity\User $featurePartner
     * @return Art
     */
    public function addFeaturePartner(\Main\UserBundle\Entity\User $featurePartner)
    {
        $this->feature_partner[] = $featurePartner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove feature_partner
     *
     * @param \Main\UserBundle\Entity\User $featurePartner
     */
    public function removeFeaturePartner(\Main\UserBundle\Entity\User $featurePartner)
    {
        $this->feature_partner->removeElement($featurePartner);
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Main\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setUser(\Main\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Main\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Add tags
     *
     * @param \Main\ArtBundle\Entity\Tags $tags
     * @return Art
     */
    public function addTag(\Main\ArtBundle\Entity\Tags $tags)
    {
        $this->tags[] = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tags
     *
     * @param \Main\ArtBundle\Entity\Tags $tags
     */
    public function removeTag(\Main\ArtBundle\Entity\Tags $tags)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tags);
    }

    /**
     * Add visits
     *
     * @param \Main\ArtBundle\Entity\ArtVisit $visits
     * @return Art
     */
    public function addVisit(\Main\ArtBundle\Entity\ArtVisit $visits)
    {
        $this->visits[] = $visits;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove visits
     *
     * @param \Main\ArtBundle\Entity\ArtVisit $visits
     */
    public function removeVisit(\Main\ArtBundle\Entity\ArtVisit $visits)
    {
        $this->visits->removeElement($visits);
    }

    /**
     * Get visits
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getVisits()
    {
        return $this->visits;
    }

    /**
     * Set locale
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locale
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \Main\StorageBundle\Entity\Image $image
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setImage(\Main\StorageBundle\Entity\Image $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \Main\StorageBundle\Entity\Image 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set viewed
     *
     * @param integer $viewed
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setViewed($viewed)
    {
        $this->viewed = $viewed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get viewed
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getViewed()
    {
        return $this->viewed;
    }

    /**
     * Set thumbs
     *
     * @param \Main\LikeBundle\Entity\Thumb $thumbs
     * @return Art
     */
    public function setThumbs(Thumb $thumbs = null)
    {
        $this->thumbs = $thumbs;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get thumbs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $thumbs
     */
    public function getThumbs()
    {
        return $this->thumbs;
    }

    /**
     * Add thumb
     *
     * @param \Main\LikeBundle\Entity\Thumb $thumb
     * @return $this $thumbs
     */
    public function addThumb(Thumb $thumb)
    {
        $this->thumbs[] = $thumb;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove thumbs
     *
     * @param \Main\LikeBundle\Entity\Thumb $thumbs
     */
    public function removeThumb(\Main\LikeBundle\Entity\Thumb $thumbs)
    {
        $this->thumbs->removeElement($thumbs);
    }

    /**
     * Count all Thumbs of the piece of art.
     */
    public function countAllThumbs() {
        return $this->thumbs->count();
    }

    /**
     * Check weather a user has thumbed a piece of art or not.
     */
    public function isThumbed($user) {

        // my first Closure :D
        $p = function($key, $element) use ($user) {
             return $element->getUser() == $user;
        };

        return $this->thumbs->exists($p);
    }

    /**
     * Get the thumb object from a special user.
     */
    public function getThumbFromUser ($user) {

        $p = function($element) use ($user) {
            return $element->getUser() == $user;
        };

        return $this->thumbs->filter($p);
    }


}
```

**The KNP Pagination Configuration** (in config.yml)

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: ::Pagination\twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: ::Pagination\sortable_link.html.twig                         # sort link template
```

I have dumped the pagination object in the controller and in the template as well. Everytime the params are there (direction= asc or desc) something like this is in the url:

```
?sort=a.id&direction=desc&page=1
```

but if I click on the link to change the direction: nothing change!!

I believe the knp pagination has a bug! Or I am very stupid ;)

If anyone can help me, I will be very happy!

Greetings Michael

Comment: How is defined the id column in the entity object? can you post the related code?

Comment: Yes, I added the Target (Entity) to paginate and also the configuration in the config.yml , which is the standard configuration. But ok, perhaps it can help anyway.

Comment: try change the visibility of the field `id`from `private` to `protected`

Comment: I have the solution. It was a bug. The mistake was in the Bundle. I changed the versions. No it works fine for me with knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle (2.4.1) knplabs/knp-components (1.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

For me, I created a new file knp_paginator.yaml and not knp_paginator.yml and I added this configuration and evrything works:

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                       # number of links shown in the pagination menu (e.g: you have 10 pages, a page_range of 3, on the 5th page you'll see links to page 4, 5, 6)
    default_options:
        page_name: page                 # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort           # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction  # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                  # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
        filter_field_name: filterField  # filter field query parameter name
        filter_value_name: filterValue  # filter value query parameter name
    template:
        pagination: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/twitter_bootstrap_v4_pagination.html.twig'     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template
        filtration: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/filtration.html.twig'  # filters template
```